# QUnit Multiple asyncTest with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

What should happen is, that when add1 is complete, then add2 should be called, and then add3, but with this code it does not work.

Add2 gets called to fast, and the same goes for add3.

```
asyncTest('add1', function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
     test('add1 t1', function () {
         ok(1==1, 'ok');
     });
     QUnit.start();
  }, 500);
});

asyncTest('add2', function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
     test('add2 t1', function () {
         ok(2==2, 'ok');
     });
     QUnit.start();
  }, 500);
});

asyncTest('add3', function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
     test('add3 t1', function () {
         ok(3==3, 'ok');
     });
     QUnit.start();
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Nesting tests like this is a very non-standard use. I'm not sure what benefit you get by doing so. Can you explain why you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things to mention here. First of all, I'm assuming that you are actually using the `ok()` assertion... there is no `test()` assertion. That said, when I run the code you have above, but with the `ok()` assertion, the tests do run in order. **However**, in general you should not be writing tests that depend on one another. This can cause all sorts of problems including race conditions, environment pollution, and others. You should try to write tests that are [idempotent](http://jasonpolites.github.io/tao-of-testing/ch4-1.1.html#rule-10-ensure-tests-are-isolated-and-idempotent).

QUnit does run tests in the order they are defined, with one exception: on reruns of test files with failing tests the library will rerun failed tests first. You can disable this with the [`reorder` config option](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.config/).

Basically, the answer here is that the code you have (except for `ok() versus`test()`) works just fine for me: the tests run in order.

Answer (score 0):

Current version of QUnit has `done = assert.async();`.

```
QUnit.test("method Debug.numberOne is called", function (assert) {
  var done = assert.async(); // Pause the test
  localStorage.setItem('uid', '1');
  function checkNumberOne() {
     assert.ok(numberOneIsCalled, " detected user is development user #1");
     done();
  }
  setTimeout(checkNumberOne, 6000);
});
```

Perhaps chaining the result callbacks will help creating a synchronous behaviour.